# Can `xdotool` replace an `expect` script, waiting for a string to appear in the active window ?

Tags: bash, shell, terminal, automation, expect

I am trying to see if I can move to `xdotool` from an `expect` script.

I use and `expect` script with this spawn command

```
ssh root@IP_ADDRESS -o UserKnownHostsFile=/dev/null -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no
```

it waits for:

```
expect "$login@$addr\'s password:"
```

in other words it's a very simple script that lets you login to the server via `ssh` without having to enter a password. But beyond this `expect` is unable to do things in a "precise" manner, I've seen it sending wrong commands repeatedly and it seems unreliable for more than simple tasks.

I was wondering if perhaps [`xdotool`](http://www.semicomplete.com/projects/xdotool/) could do a better job. If `xdotool` could somehow listen to the strings on the terminal for example
and wait for:

```
"$login@$addr\'s password:"
```

Can this be done ?

The only method I can think of right now is adding `sleep` or something of that nature to my script to make it wait for the login, which could fail.

Answer (score 2):

As much as I love `xdotool` and pretty much all of [Jordan Sissel's](https://github.com/jordansissel) scripts, config files, hacks, and applications (++ Jordan!) I don't think `xdotool` is what you are looking for here.  As for `expect` there are `tcl`, `python` and `perl` variants and the logic of your script can be as sophisticated and robust as those languages allow.

I'd revisit the script and try to make it handle possible errors and login prompt changes more correctly.  The second thing I would do is not allow root login with `ssh` (actually that would be the first thing I would do).  If you are using SSH you have the full power of SSH configuration files, Public Key Encryption, Kerberos, LDAP, and other approaches to making logins convenient, secure, and easily manageable from a security policy and systems administration perspective.

Do all that and *then* think of how you could use `xdotool` - because `xdotool` rocks!

ps: check the `ssh_config` manual page: there are many secure and convenient configuration options for what you are trying to achieve here.